# Azure Service Fabric Application

Tags: c#, .net, service, azure

У меня такая проблема, прочитал статью про "Service fabric and microservices approach", установил все как [здесь](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-get-started/), прописал в PowerShell нужную строку, но буквально сразу при попытке создания нового приложения Service Fabric Application, после нажатия "ОК" (создаю свой Stateful Service, как в примере на сайте) получаю исключение от Visual Studio

> Общее исключение (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80131500)

Подскажите, как мне это исправить или может я что-то делаю не так? (И Visual Studio и PowerShell запускал от имени администратора).

Comment: Попробуйте то же самое на другом компе. Может быть, просто что-то с конфигурацией VS или винды не то. Если на другом всё заработает, то либо VS, либо Win переставляйте.

Comment: Пробывал на Windows Server 2012, к сожалению то же самое

Answer (score 0):

У меня была эта проблема (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80131500) при создании проекта Service Fabric в русской версии Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. Установил English Language Pack и выбрал английский язык в настройках, после этого всё заработало.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48157